# Will there be standardization of scope guard/scope exit idioms?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, scopeguard

Running a lambda on scope exit seems like such a basic thing, I would expect it to be standardized. Things like `unique_ptr` are better, when they apply, but I find there is an endless supply of "one-off" destructors are needed, especially when leveraging C-style libraries. Does anyone know if this is coming?

Comment: In which cases are you using lambdas on scope exit?

Comment: Waiting for thread pool work items to complete before closing the thread pool is a good example (even when an exception is thrown you still have to wait or it will crash the workers). It's always possible to create a full C++ wrapper for each thing you do, but its so much extra code in the cases where you use it one time.

Comment: Write a proposal? I happen to like [Stefanus Du Toit](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/C%2B%2B11%20in%20the%20Wild%20-%20Techniques%20from%20a%20Real%20Codebase/auto.h)'s implementation (though I have no idea why he called it `Auto`)

Comment: @Barry: That is actually Arthur O'Dwyer's implementation - see https://goo.gl/0t8bXR

Comment: @sdt Oops. Reading comprehension fail on my part. Though comment remains about `Auto` :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[n4189](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189) is a proposal to add `make_scope_exit` wrappers, and other similar resource handlers, to the language.  It is based off of the relatively famous `scope_guard` talk.

The most recent "current paper status" from LWG is in 2013, prior to the above date.

The contents of C++1z (hopefully C++17) are yet to be determined.

[C++1z status for clang](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) does not mention it.  [C++1z TS for clang](http://libcxx.llvm.org/ts1z_status.html) does not mention it.

The paper itself contains an example implementation.  I do not know what licensing terms it is under.

Comment: It [seems to have passed LEWG](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6), but looks like it will need better wording before it can be adopted. N4189's wording is pretty bad.

Answer (score 10):

[It would appear](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6) that the current version of the scope exit paper, [P0052](http://wg21.link/P0052), will be going into the Library Fundamentals v3, for likely adoption in the **Post**-C++17 standard.

In short, not gonna happen for C++17. Sorry.

Comment: Final comment that there tells about a proposal to move it to IS. Can't say whether it's gonna happen.

Comment: @pepper_chico What is IS?

Comment: @Jens: The International Standard. It didn't make it, btw.